# Intercept Axios request with global JS methods

Tags: vue.js, axios, xmlhttprequest

I have a site with web components based architecture, where each web component may be a separate Vue app with it's own API layer integrated via Axios. I need to implement Auth middleware for all HTTP requests, coming from either root app or web component app. I cannot use Axios built-in interceptors mechanism as there will be multiple instances of Axios. Is there a way I can do it with global JS methods? I know there is [some browser extension based API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) out there, but that doesn't seem like something I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anybody else is interested, I have solved it with service worker. You can subscribe to `fetch` events and respond according to your auth logics. Your service worker code will look something like following:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
    const isAuthorised = await checkIsAuthorized(); // your auth API layer
    if (!isAuthorised) {
        const response = new Response(null, {
            status: 401,
            statusText: 'Unauthorised',
        });
        event.respondWith(response);
        return;
    }
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});
```

Service worker is able to intercept axios requests from shadow DOM as well, so it's a good match for web components case.

Besides, there is a [nice article by Bartosz Polnik](https://itnext.io/using-service-worker-as-an-auth-relay-5abc402878dd) on implementing auth layer using service worker.